# Add answers from a loop into a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, loops

Sorry if I don't make any sense here, I've only been learning python for a few weeks, but I want to take the answers I get from a loop and put them into a list or an array.

Here's the code:

```
import itertools
n = 100 
r = RandomState()
p = np.zeros(n)
for _ in itertools.repeat(p, 10):
    n = 100
    for k in range(99):
        p[0] = 0.0
        for i in range(n-1):
            if (r.rand() >= 0.5):
                p[i+1] = p[i] + 1.
            else:
                p[i+1] = p[i] - 1.
d = [p[99]]
print(d)
```

Basically I want it to generate 100 random numbers, each one adding to the one before it. Then I take the final value at p[99], then I repeat the whole thing 10 times and take each final value, but python gives me the result in this format:

```
[11.0]
[15.0]
[11.0]
[-7.0]
[-7.0]
[13.0]
[-1.0]
[-1.0]
[1.0]
[21.0]
```

Instead I want all of the values to be together in one list or array. If anyone can help with that I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a empty list and append the result to it

```
import itertools
n = 100 
res = []
r = np.random.RandomState()
p = np.zeros(n)
for _ in itertools.repeat(p, 10):
    n = 100
    for k in range(99):
        p[0] = 0.0
        for i in range(n-1):
            if (r.rand() >= 0.5):
                p[i+1] = p[i] + 1.
            else:
                p[i+1] = p[i] - 1.
    res.append(p[99])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[-11.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, -15.0, -5.0, 11.0, 5.0, -1.0, -9.0]
```